# Change diagonal plots in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm not able to change the diagonal plots in a ggpair-plot. I would like to change their appearance in general and maybe starting by leaving them blank.
This is how I think it should be:

```
ggpairs(data=df,
             columns=1:3,
             diag = list(discrete = "blank"),
             title="APD pool",
             mapping=ggplot2::aes(colour = Irradiated)
            )
```

but it ends with a density curve(?!) in the diagonal elements. 
Due to Robin's comment I tried it with

```
ggpairs(data=df,
             columns=1:3,
             diag = list(continous = "blank"),
             title="APD pool",
             mapping=ggplot2::aes(colour = Irradiated)
            )
```

but it doesn't change.

[image: Plot]

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Reference: https://rdrr.io/cran/GGally/man/ggpairs.html

Comment: The data are continuous, not discrete.

Comment: Thank you but this didn't change anything

Comment: It should be continuous, not continous :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You spelled `continuous` wrongly. Your code spelt it "continous" instead.

When you use `diag`, you have to pass in a list that may only contain the variables `continuous`, `discrete`, and `na`. When you assign a value to `continuous`, it can only be **exactly one** of

- 'densityDiag'
- 'barDiag'
- 'blankDiag'

So instead of `diag = list(continous = "blank")` you want to have `diag = list(continuous = "blankDiag")` instead. That would do the trick:
[image]